# Parsing double quote with new line from CSV using jackson-dataformat-csv

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have the following CSV format:

```
id,name,description,age
23,Anna,"Self-made
Chef
Shoemaker",23
```

The double-quotes are only present if the attribute is multi-line. While I am already been able to read the normal CSV correctly:

```java
@Bean
public CsvMapper csvMapper() {
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    csvMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    csvMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    return csvMapper;
}
```

I tried adding a new feature:

```java
csvMapper.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_COLUMNS, true);
```

But it makes the library skip failed rows. How do I parse the given format and get the whole `Self-made\n Chef\n Shoemaker` into the description attribute?

Answer (score 0):

According to my reading of the code in the `CSVDecoder` class ([link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/blob/2.14/csv/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/impl/CsvDecoder.java)), the Jackson CSV parser in version 2.14 will correctly parse double-quoted strings that have embedded line-breaks.   Look for the `_nextQuotedString` method.  No attribute needs to be set to enable this.  It happens unconditionally.

Indeed, it looks like the relevant lines of the code have not changed in at least 5 years.

So ... if the CSV parser is not working for you (without that `Feature`), my diagnosis is:

- either you are using a really old version of Jackson,
- or the apparently incomplete values you are seeing are injected somewhere / somehow *after* CSV parsing.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the Question, and tell us the version(s) of the Jackson dependencies you are using.